# How to measure wort oxygenation

Tags: equipment, aeration, oxygenation, measurements

As a follow-up to a couple of other questions:

- [How to Properly Oxygenate Wort](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/2725/how-to-properly-oxygenate-wort)
- [Wort aeration on a budget](https://homebrew.stackexchange.com/questions/2690/wort-aeration-on-a-budget)

How do you measure oxygenation of wort?  What methods are available for a beginner brewer (low-cost), or a more seasoned veteran?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a relatively inexpensive procedure, known as the [Winkler method](http://www.ecy.wa.gov/programs/wq/plants/management/joysmanual/4oxygen.html), that's used by ecologists to measure the oxygen concentration in streams and ponds.  It relies on titration using sodium thiosulfate (among other chemicals).

I don't think this test works on wort, however, due to wort chemistry.  At the very least, titration would be difficult with any beer darker than a pale.

The best method is to use a dissolved oxygen (DO) meter.  Good DO meters cost around $1000, although I've seen a few handheld units online in the $300 - $500 range.

It's not very common practice to measure wort oxygenation, sadly.  Most microbreweries don't even invest in this equipment, although more recently, the trend is changing.

Comment: If you have maxed out a lot of other things in your process and really want to make great beer, a DO meter can be a great investment even for home brewing or small craft brewery.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know of any homebrewers that are actually measuring the ppm of O2 dissolved in their wort.  The best practice is to get an O2 cylinder with a medical grade flow meter (not a pressure regulator, but a flow meter).  Then experiment with time on the meter and good results in the final product.